# What Datascrap in Curl ? and how to do it in PHP?

Tags: php

how to do data scraping in curl php ? That content automatically get copied in database.
Can anybody have easy sample code that i can understand data scraping.

Comment: Too Broad. What have you tried ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

stackoverflow is not a tutorial website it's for Q&A. Try this anyway

http://www.jacobward.co.uk/web-scraping-with-php-curl-part-1/

https://www.google.com.eg/search?q=web+scraping+with+crul+php&oq=web+scraping+with+crul+php&aqs=chrome..69i57.5504j0j1&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=web+scraping+with+curl+php&spell=1